# How to interpret HTTP Status Code 302 in an IIS web log

Tags: iis, http-status-codes

I am looking at my IIS web log and notice some log records with an `sc-status` of 302.

[image: Screenshot of IIS web log subsample]

I did [research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success) and am only more confused.

At first, it looks simple, if a little vague.

> "This is an example of industry practice contradicting the standard.
>   [...] Therefore, HTTP/1.1 added status codes 303 and 307 to
>   distinguish between the two behaviours.[25] However, some Web
>   applications and frameworks use the 302 status code as if it were the
>   303."

While I understand the concept, I am not sure which meaning to apply when viewing an IIS web log. Do I treat the 302 status code as a 303 ("See Other" -- a way to redirect to a new URL) or as a 307 ("Temporary Redirect")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`307` causes a redirect using the same "verb" that the original url was requested with. That allows `POST` data to be preserved. By contrast, `301/302` will always cause a `GET` of the new url, losing any POST data that may have been present.

As well, with `301/302`, the browser can cache the response and always go to the new url, bypassing the original url. `307` requires that the original URL be hit again, even if it does end up being another redirect.